# Add variable to mfc dialog control

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc, dialog

This is a very simple problem, but I could not find a solution to it. I have a dialog A, which when clicked a button opens another dialog B with a single edit box. I want to add an integer variable to it. 

The usual way of adding variables which is right clicking the edit box and "add variable" is greyed out. I presume that it's because I haven't declared a separate class for the dialog, since the variable is used only in Dialog A code I don't want to add a separate class for Dialog B.

What should I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to customise the behaviour of dialog B in *any* way (including adding variables for controls), you **must** declare a class for it.

You say that the variable is only used in dialog A code, but that doesn't mean that dialog A is the *owner* of that variable. Dialog B owns it, so dialog B needs a class.

Comment: for dialog resources you add class derieved from CDialog, usually the name of derieved class same as dialog name. To add variable right click dialog in design view and add variable quite simple isnot it?

Comment: @AliKazmi yes it's simple to do it and the OP knows that, as I understand it he's just asking if it's necessary just for a single edit box.

Comment: If I add a separate class, wouldn't I have to declare the variable in the same class? If so I will have to access it through a public method. Isn't there a simpler method? (seems a lot of trouble for a single variable)

Comment: @Madz yes the variable will belong in that same class and will be `public` by default. You can wrap it in an accessor function if you like but many people don't bother. It does seem a lot of trouble but it's the right way to do it and it will be much easier to extend it to include other variables if/when you expand your functionality in future. FWIW, you probably did more typing to ask this question than you would have to generate the dialog ;-)